# Source for a drush in lemaaleh mimecha

Tags: sources-mekorot, pirke-avot-ethicsof, drush

There is a famous *drush* that is brought by *Nefesh haChayim* in the beginning of the 4th chapter of *shaar* 1, and also discussed in *Ruach Chayim*. The *mishnah* in [*Pirkei Avos* 2:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.2.1?lang=bi) says *da ma lemaaleh mimeka* (know what is above you), and *Nefesh haChayim* suggests to read "know that what is above -- is from you," i.e., that you are the source of the changes that take place in the spiritual worlds.

A similar take is attributed to Ba'al Shem Tov.

I have heard that the original source for the *drush* is *Megaleh Amukos*, but could not find it there. Would anyone know if that is really the source (and if so, where it is in the *sefer*), or there is an earlier work which brings it down?

Thank you so much!

Comment: In Chabad chassidus it's usually attributed to the Mezritcher Maggid: https://chabadlibrary.org/books/magid/ot/47/480.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is it? [Megalleh Amukos al HaTorah](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20578&st=&pgnum=234), at the end of parshas Emor

> כאשר יתן מום בזה העולם כן ינתן בו בדיוקנא דיהיה לעילא דפגם בנשמתא דיליה לעילא כי שבר מה שהוא פוגם למטה פוגם תחת שבר דליעלא ומזה הטעם כתב עין תחת עין הוא על ממון ולא עין ממש אבל רזא דא הוא על עין דלעיל' דע מה לעמלה ממך וכו' אתה לידע ענין כי עין דלעילא תחת עין דלתתא הזכר עין ושן שבהן עבד יוצא ש"ע נהורין

He doesn't speak it out explicitly like the Nefesh HaChaim does but he says whatever you do here affects the upper spheres and then brings the teaching from Avos